# history.replaceState not working for firefox v56+

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, html5-history

In my application, **To Hide some information in URL i am using below code**.

```
history.replaceState ({}, "", "bar.html");
```

It is working in all the browsers **except firefox latest version (v56+)**

In Firefox, if i press F5 then it is going back to previous URL which i have already replaced with above code.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you find out anything on that issue? i've been struggling with a bug that has similar symptoms

Comment: In the latest Firefox version, this bug seems fixed. Have a try!

Comment: oh shoot, i was hoping for a reproduction on the latest version (i'm seeing this on firefox quantum, i.e. 66.0.3 64-bit). what version exactly do you now have as *latest*, by the way?

Comment: Well, I understand your problem and it's hard to answer :( What i observed related to this issue is that it's coming in certain versions after 56.* But i am not sure from which version it's get fixed.
I am also using version 66 right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [open issue on `Bugzilla`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422334).

[Video Example 1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8933680) and [Video Example 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sNy9T5HUPmfQbZznoR_jMgt9OMTgTkJN/view) explain how to reproduce the bug.

> **Conditions:**
>
> 1. Mozilla Firefox version only `56+`
> 2. Single Page Application
> 3. For routing uses `history.replaceState`, all parameters not null
>
> **Steps:**
>
> 1. Login & redirect to main page base `URL`
> 2. Navigate on any application tab & replace URL parameters
> 3. Press `F5`, `cmd + r` or click `Refresh` button
> 4. Ups!.. Again open main page with base `URL` (but in other browsers we see the selected tab and the correct URL)

The same behaviour is experienced when removing query strings from the url.

It could be caused from the following behaviour (I quote [Vadim Goncharov](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/user_profile?user_id=607420))

> The main problem is that after using `history.replaceState` and then clicking `cmd+r/f5` we will see that browser **sends replaced (correct)** `url` to server, but shows **incorrect url** both in `location.search` and *browser url bar*. And this behaviour continues (if click to "cmd+r/f5") until we click "enter" on browser url bar.

First **Workaround** posted from [Felix Lee](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/user_profile?user_id=420108)

> Before calling `history.replaceState`, do
>     `location.hash = location.hash;`
>
> Setting `hash` to itself has no effect, but **makes the bug go away**.

This workaround is not ideal and [mtomalley](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/user_profile?user_id=627012) adds a **second Workaround**

> The browser is requesting a different URL than what is shown in the location bar....
>
> Additionally, the workaround isn't ideal because if the `URL` doesn't already have a `hash`, `location.hash = location.hash` adds one, calls `popstate`, and **adds a history entry**.
>
> An alternate workaround that is much less simple:
>
> 1. Use whatever means available to your backend technology to expose the request `URI` on the client
> 2. On page load (before any client routing code), check the `URI` against `window.location`
> 3. If they're different, use `replaceState` to fix it.
>
> The location will briefly show the incorrect URL on any reload, but at least it'll be fixed and routing can work as expected...

**Third Workaround** proposed from [Mathis Wiehl](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/user_profile?user_id=560712)

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) { location.replace(location) });
```

> This way the state of the js location is flushed to FFs location in cases of refreshes and tab closes (which by the way have the same issue when reopened with e.g. ⌘+⇧+t).

The above workaround from **Mathis** has the following issue (I quote [jimmyhmiller](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/user_profile?user_id=562099))

> Next.js tried using the workaround that Mathis mentioned above and it caused some bad issues for them. Details here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/6896

A new bug was experienced with the above **workaround**, explained in the issue [#6882](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6882)

> when landing on a page that contains query parameters, the browser becomes "locked" to that page and programmatically or manually navigating to a different same-domain page insta-redirects back to the original. note that this does not start happening until a query parameter is involved in the url, totally bizarre

I also include a list of [other mozilla related issues with history.replaceState](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=history.replaceState).

I keep myself available for further analysis, research, improvements to this posts and I am happy to receive your feedback.

Comment: @Eliran Malka there is an [open issue in `Bugzilla`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422334). I included the solutions in my answer. I am happy to rewrite the answer, extend my search and do improvements.

Comment: @EliranMalka my pleasure! :-) Thanks

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks for the bounty, please contact me for any further assistance